# Drodpwn goes off the mobile width when expanded in lighnining component

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

I have one lightning component. In that lightning component, I have one dropdown which goes out of the mobile width when expanded in mobile devices.

How can i make it responsive so that its width gets adjusted according to mobile device width?

Here is one snapshot.

[image]

Comment: It'll probably help if you share the markup for your component.